# JQUERY Function within a function does not work

Tags: jquery

I want to run a Perl script with url parameters. 
I can not understand why the second function "callScript" does not work,

Not working:

```
 jQuery('#hideshow').live('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#content').toggle('show');
    var m = 'kkk';
    var l = 'http://192.116.153.90/cgi-bin/RRD/y.pl?user=' + m;
    alert(l);



            function callScript(){
   \$.get(l, function(data){
          \$("#response").html("The Perl script says: " + data); 

   })

}
```

working:

```
    <div id="response"></div>           
<script>
var m = 'bibi';
var l = 'http://192.116.153.90/cgi-bin/RRD/y.pl?user=' + g;
alert(l);
  function callScript(){
   \$.get(l, function(data){
          \$("#response").html("The Perl script says: " + data); 
   })
}

</script>
```

Comment: what version of JQuery you using? and make a jsfiddle

Comment: 1.4.2, That I have a DataTable- http://datatables.net/index

Answer (score 0):

You have a <script> tag in the middle of your javascript. You should also be using .on instead of .live (https://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: Sorry, an error copying but the problem exists even without this